# MolView is unable to generate correct 3D structure for hydroxypropadiene

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-structure, software, erratum

[MolView](http://molview.org/) is unable to generate the correct structure of hydroxypropadiene. It instead generates the structure of acrolein (which has the same molecular formula). Why is this so? Is it because hydroxypropadiene is so unstable that the calculations done while generating the structure degenerate it to acrolein?

[image: Screenshot]

MolView is using the default GLMol renderer. Switching to JMol or ChemDoodle does not change the structure.

**EDIT**: The exact workflow I used was open MolView, delete the caffiene molecule, draw this molecule and click the *2D to 3D* button. The generated URL is `http://molview.org/?cid=7847`, which, when pasted in a browser, interestingly redirects to Acrolein and not the compound that was drawn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect MolView simply fails to parse the compound's name you are trying to input. "Hydroxypropadiene" isn't the proper name, at least not by IUPAC standards. According to Google services, this name [doesn't appear in any textbooks](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22hydroxypropadiene%22) and [is mentioned only in three research articles from 1980s](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22hydroxypropadiene%22).

The PIN [propa‐1,2‐dien‐1‐ol](http://molview.org/?q=Propa%E2%80%901,2%E2%80%90dien%E2%80%901%E2%80%90ol) appears to work correctly with MolView:

[image: Rendered image of propa‐1,2‐dien‐1‐ol in MolView running in Chromium browser v. 81.0.4044.138]

When you are trying to get a 3D image from the 2D drawing, there is the following issue which MolView usually reports (not sure why you haven't received the message):

> Failed to load structure from sketcher. **This structure may contain allenes, which cannot be represented in the SMILES notation.**

[MolView relies on SMILES](http://blog.molview.org/2016/10/10/issues-in-3d-resolving/) in order to fetch the 3D structure.
The problem is likely that [Ketcher](https://github.com/ggasoftware/ketcher) generates wrong SMILES because [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/7847) indeed receives `C=CC=O` instead of the proper one, `C=C=CO`.

Comment: Interesting. I thought molview worked on the structure and not the name of the compound?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Ah, you were trying to *draw* the compound, not generate the structure by name. I added some info with respect to that.

Comment: Thanks. That clears it up. I received a message "the generated structure may be incorrect". I did not receive a message that specifically stated that Allenes could not be generated.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Yeah, the message might pop up inconsistently depending on how you draw the structure. Maybe try to add H atoms explicitly, this might help to get the error message. Also, note that allenes *can* normally be represented with SMILES, so the error message is likely to be interpreted more like "*we cannot reliably generate SMILES in your particular case with our algorithm*".